# SSRS Dynamically change the cell background and font color

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I need to change the Table Cell Background color to Yellow and Font color to Bold / Red for values which are less than 80.

Cell Expression is  **=Fields!Mark.Value**

How to change the Cell Background Color / Fill the Color to Yellow ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nearly everything in SSRS is an expression, so you can use VBA code to conditionally set the property value.

To set the background colour, set the `BackgroundColor` property of the table cell to be:

```
=IIF(Fields!Mark.Value < 80, "Yellow", "White")
```

To set the font to bold, set the `Font`-`FontWeight` property of the table cell to be:

```
=IIF(Fields!Mark.Value < 80, "Bold", "Normal")
```

To make the text red, set the `Color` property of the table cell to be:

```
=IIF(Fields!Mark.Value < 80, "Red", "Black")
```

Comment: Same idea for making the text red - added expression to answer

Comment: I would use `Me.Value` instead of `Fields!Mark.Value` for code that is easier to copy from cell to cell or report to report.

Comment: just amazing tip :)

Answer (score 0):

1. select textbox ->right click-> go to property
2. font->color->give your expression ex : =iif(Fields!status.Value="1","Green","Red")